# Linphone-web-plugin build stuck on OSX

Tags: voip, firebreath, linphone

I'm trying to build linphone-web-plugin on OS X 10.9.3 with Xcode 5.1.1 installed. I have followed instructions in their README file. I have tryied to build it using XCode 4.6.3 (with xcodebuild command, not directly from the Xcode). Linphone-web-plugin is using firebreath-1.7.

The problem is that build always get stuck on line:

```
-- Check size of unsigned long long - done
```

It doesn't throw any errors, it just stays there forever.

Did anyone had this problem while building linphone-web-plugin?
Linphone-web-plugin can be found [here](http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html).

Comment: That is decidedly odd; what version of cmake are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.8.12.2 cmake. In their README file they are recommending to use version 2.8.2 or greater.

Comment: It is possible that something in a newer version of cmake broke things; I've never tried building it, but I'm the primary developer of FireBreath, which it is built on.  You might try building FBTestPlugin from the firebreath source and see if that will build